# Using jinja to generate a CSV file

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm not quite sure if Jinja is the right tool for the job, but seeing as it's used elsewhere in our environment I thought I'd try and use this as an exercise to familiarise myself with it.

I have a list `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I need to write the values in it to create a CSV file. All values in the CSV file will be fixed except for the values in a.

So I imagine a template file will look something like this (I know this is not Jinja2 syntax):

```
a[0], 'something',
a[1], 'else',
a[2], 'but',
.
.
a[5], 'repeated statement',
a[6], 'repeated statement',
.
a[8], 'here endeth the lesson',
```

Can I access the elements in 'a' by index like I would in Python and create my output file?

Comment: why don't you use built-in `csv` module instead?

Comment: Hey @Marat yes, that's what I'm doing right now. This was more to familiarise myself with Jinja, but it looks like it's the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your end goal is, but jinja is more of a templating tool for generating views, rather than some kind of file. Like what @Marat said, you could use the `csv` module to create a csv file.

However, if your real purpose is to use jinja to create some type of table view where the values in your list are populated in the table, then you can certainly do that in jinja.

In your HTML view, you would do something like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List[idx]</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        {%- for item in a -%}
        <tr>
            <td>a[{{ loop.index - 1 }}]</td>
            <td>{{ item }}</td>
        </tr>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, you have to pass your `a` list as a context variable to your jinja in order for this to work. I'm assuming you're using Flask as your framework:

```
@app.route('/your-route')
def your_route_function():
    ...  # your code for creating the 'a' list
    ...  # more code
    return render_template('yourhtml.html', a=a)
```

Now, if you want to access your list by index, that's possible too. You would have to determine the length of your list though using jinja's [`length`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#length) filter:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>List[idx]</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        {%- for idx in range(a|length) -%}
        <tr>
            <td>a[{{ idx }}]</td>
            <td>{{ a[idx] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In our environment it is used to generate repeatable text files for various purposes. I think you've put me on the right track. Let me test and get back.

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question. Furthermore according to the Jinja2 documentation "A Jinja template is simply a text file. Jinja can generate any text-based format (HTML, XML, CSV, LaTeX, etc.). A Jinja template doesn’t need to have a specific extension: .html, .xml, or any other extension is just fine.".